# Create local mapping on Team Foundation Services workspace using tf vc commands

Tags: tfs

I'm trying to create a local mapping to an already existing workspace using tf vc commands on the command prompt. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Tf workfold` command to realize the mapping. In the command option, there is `/map` option which *specifies an association between a local folder and the Team Foundation version control server folder*.

The syntax is as follows:

```
tf workfold [/map serverfolder localfolder] [/collection:TeamProjectCollectionUrl] 

[/workspace:workspacename][/login:username,[password]
```

So the command is like the below:

```
tf workfold $/projects/MyTeamProject/* C:\LocalWorkfold\TeamProject 

/map  /collection:http://servername:8080/tfs/defaultcollection

/workspace:"WorkspaceName"

/login:username,password
```